# Alternating row color two at a time in tables

Tags: tables, color

How can I achieve alternating row colors in tables for two rows at a time? So two rows should have the same color, then two other rows, and so on.
In the following example

```
Bla1 & reference1 \\
& Description1 \\
```

should have one color and

```
Bla2 & reference2 \\
& Description2 \
```

should have another. Then start alternating again. How can this be achieved?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\section{Section}
   \begin{tabular}{lp{10cm}}
    \hline
    \textbf{Col 1} & \textbf{Col 2} \\ \hline
    Bla1 & reference1 \\
    & Description1 \\ 
    Bla2 & reference2 \\
    & Description2 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Gonzalo Medina's solution works fine, however if one uses the `glossaries` package the acronyms table will have row colors as well.
How could I prevent the acronyms table to have this behavior?

Comment: If the alternating colors must apply only to one particular table, move the `\rowcolors` line from the preamble to a group containing the table the should have the colors; for example:  `{\rowcolors{1}{white}{blue!10}\begin{tabular}{Lp{10cm}}<contents>\end{tabular}}` (notice the extra pair of outer braces).

Comment: @GonzaloMedina It's more like: It applies to 99 tables, but not for the acronyms table :(

Comment: Then you can use `\rowcolors{1}{}{}` before the acronyms.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's a possible solution; the idea is to use an auxiliary counter for the rows, and depending on the value of this counter module 4, to set `\rownum` (internally used to decide wich color apply to a row) to 0 or to 1; the `etoolbox` package was used to patch `tabular` to set the `row` counter to 0:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\rowcolors{1}{white}{blue!10}

\newcounter{row}
\newcolumntype{L}{%
  >{\stepcounter{row}%
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\j}{int(Mod(\therow,4))}
  \ifnum\j<2 
    \global\rownum=1
  \else
    \global\rownum=0
  \fi}%
l}

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{tabular}{\setcounter{row}{0}}

\begin{document}

\section{Section}

\begin{tabular}{Lp{10cm}}
\rowcolor{blue!10}Bla1 & reference1 \\
& Description1 \\
Bla2 & reference2 \\    
& Description2 \\
Bla3 & reference3 \\    
& Description3 \\ 
Bla4 & reference4 \\    
& Description4 \\ 
Bla5 & reference5 \\    
& Description5 \\ 
Bla6 & reference6 \\    
& Description6 \\ 
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's probably better to `\setcounter{row}{0}` before the tabular: in case two tabulars of this kind are used the previous end value would be retained.

Comment: @egreg you're right. I'll add the correction. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `xcolor` package `\rowcolors` command but just modify slightly to only change every other row.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\rowcolors{0}{red}{yellow}
\newcount\xrownum
\makeatletter
 \def\@rowc@lors{\noalign{%  
  \global\advance\xrownum\@ne
  \ifodd\xrownum
  \global\advance\rownum\@ne
  \fi
  }\@rowcolors}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Section}
   \begin{tabular}{lp{10cm}}
    \hline
    \textbf{Col 1} & \textbf{Col 2} \\ \hline
    Bla1 &{reference1} \\
    Bla1 &{reference1} \\
    Bla1 &{reference1} \\
    Bla1 &{reference1} \\
    Bla1 &{reference1} \\
    & Description1 \\ 
    & Description1 \\ 
    Bla2 & {reference2} \\
    & Description2 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

In ConTeXt, the same idea as Gonzalo's solution can be implemented as follows:

```
\definecolor[lightblue][r=0.8,g=0.8,b=1]
\defineconversion[tablecolor][lightblue,lightblue,white,white]

\startsetups doublerow:color
  \setupTABLE[row][each]
             [background=color,
              backgroundcolor={\convertnumber{tablecolor}{\positiverow}}]
\stopsetups

\starttext
\startTABLE[setups={doublerow:color}]
  \dorecurse{10}
    {\NC One \NC Two \NC Three \NC \NR}
\stopTABLE
\stoptext
```

Answer (score 0):

With `nicematrix`. (v. 6.0 of 2021-08-10).

You won't see thin white lines in the colored panels, whatever PDF viewer you use.

```
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\section{Section}

\begin{NiceTabular}{lp{10cm}}[color-inside]
\rowlistcolors{blue!15,=,white,=}
  Bla1 & reference1 \\
  & Description1 \\
  Bla2 & reference2 \\    
  & Description2 \\
  Bla3 & reference3 \\    
  & Description3 \\ 
  Bla4 & reference4 \\    
  & Description4 \\ 
  Bla5 & reference5 \\    
  & Description5 \\ 
  Bla6 & reference6 \\    
  & Description6 \\ 
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

In the instruction `\rowlistcolors{blue!15,=,white,=}`, the symbol `=` is used to specify a color equal to the previous one in the list.

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]