# vertical align and color in table with multirow

Tags: spacing, color

I have the following table:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
    \begin{tabular}{l c c c}
    \toprule
Group & Par. & Measure & Metric\\
    \midrule
\rowcolor{gray!25} \cellcolor{white} Group 1 & & 1 &  \(Formula_1=\displaystyle\frac{A}{B}\cdot 2 \)\\ \addlinespace[3pt]
\rowcolor{gray!25} \cellcolor{white} & F &  2 &  \(Formula_2=\displaystyle\frac{C}{D}\cdot 3.1 \) \\ \addlinespace[3pt]  
\rowcolor{gray!25} \cellcolor{white} & & 3 & \(Formula_3=\displaystyle\frac{E}{F}\cdot 2 \)\\  \addlinespace[3pt]

& & 3a &\\ \addlinespace[3pt]
& E & 3b &\\ 
&  & 4 & \(Formula_4=\displaystyle\frac{G}{H}\)\\ \addlinespace[12 pt]


\rowcolor{gray!25} \cellcolor{white} Group 2 & & 5 & \(Formula_5=\displaystyle\frac{I}{J}\)\\ \addlinespace[3pt]
\rowcolor{gray!25} \cellcolor{white} & P & 6 & \(Formula_6=\displaystyle\frac{K}{L}\)\\ \addlinespace[3pt]
\rowcolor{gray!25} \cellcolor{white} & & 7 & \(Formula_7=M-N \)\\ \addlinespace[3pt]

& & 7a &\\ \addlinespace[3pt]
& N & 7b &\\ 
& & 8 & \(Formula_8=\displaystyle\frac{O}{P}\)\\ \addlinespace[3 pt]

    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \caption{Hi, I am the caption.}
  \label{measures}%
\end{table}%
\end{document}
```

That produce the following result:

[image: The table of the code presented above]

The are two clear problems that I cannot overcome:

1. The *ugly* white space between the gray rows, due to "\addlinespace[3pt]", that in turns I have put to improve the fractions readability
2. The vertical space in the gray lines with equations: I wish they were not so close to the cell top and down borders (very clear in the first row: "A/B")

What I have tried so far:

- To solve the first problem nothing serious... I tried to play with "rowcolor" and "cellcolor", with no sensible effects...
- I tried to add "\vphantom{\Huge{A}}" before

`\(Formula_1`

but it solves only half of the problem, as can be see in the following image:

[image: With "Huge"]

- I have also tried [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59250/alternating-row-color-two-at-a-time-in-tables), but it doesn't solve the problem, and it colors all the table in my document (while I wish to have only this one colored).

Hope everything is clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please *always* post full documents not just fragments, I had to guess which packages you were using (and guessed wrong the first time).

The coloured panels will grow vertically if the spacing is within rather than between the rows. There are various ways that could be done setting `\arraystretch` or `\extrarowheight` or using the `[3pt]` option to `\\` or adding an invisible "strut" more or less anything *except* booktabs line separator command would have worked here. So if you put the spacing within the cells it solves both problems the padding around teh formula increases and you don't get the white gaps:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs,colortbl,xcolor}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\newcommand\bigstrut{\rule[-20pt]{20pt}{0pt}}
\setlength\extrarowheight{7pt}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
  \centering
    \begin{tabular}{l c c c}
    \toprule
Group & Par. & Measure & Metric\\
    \midrule
\rowcolor{gray!25} \cellcolor{white} Group 1 & & 1 &\bigstrut  \(Formula_1=\displaystyle\frac{A}{B}\cdot 2 \)\\[3pt]
\rowcolor{gray!25} \cellcolor{white} & F &  2 &\bigstrut  \(Formula_2=\displaystyle\frac{C}{D}\cdot 3.1 \) \\[3pt]  
\rowcolor{gray!25} \cellcolor{white} & & 3 &\bigstrut \(Formula_3=\displaystyle\frac{E}{F}\cdot 2 \)\\[7pt]

& & 3a &\\
& E & 3b &\\ 
&  & 4 &\bigstrut \(Formula_4=\displaystyle\frac{G}{H}\)\\[6 pt]


\rowcolor{gray!25} \cellcolor{white} Group 2 & & 5 &\bigstrut \(Formula_5=\displaystyle\frac{I}{J}\)\\[3pt]
\rowcolor{gray!25} \cellcolor{white} & P & 6 &\bigstrut \(Formula_6=\displaystyle\frac{K}{L}\)\\[3pt]
\rowcolor{gray!25} \cellcolor{white} & & 7 &\bigstrut \(Formula_7=M-N \)\\[7pt]

& & 7a &\\
& N & 7b &\\ 
& & 8 & \(Formula_8=\displaystyle\frac{O}{P}\)\\

    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \caption{Hi, I am the caption.}
  \label{measures}%
\end{table}%


\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, I did prepare the full example but I posted only the table :D I have corrected it. Thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 0):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{NiceTabular}{l c c c}[cell-space-limits=2pt]
\toprule
Group & Par. & Measure & Metric \\
\midrule
Group 1 & \Block[fill=gray!25]{3-3}{}
            & 1  & \(Formula_1=\dfrac{A}{B}\cdot 2 \)\\ 
        & F & 2  & \(Formula_2=\dfrac{C}{D}\cdot 3.1 \) \\ 
        &   & 3  & \(Formula_3=\dfrac{E}{F}\cdot 2 \)\\  
        &   & 3a \\
        & E & 3b \\
        &   & 4  & \(Formula_4=\dfrac{G}{H}\)\\ 
Group 2 & \Block[fill=gray!25]{3-3}{}
            & 5  & \(Formula_5=\dfrac{I}{J}\)\\ 
        & P & 6  & \(Formula_6=\dfrac{K}{L}\)\\ 
        &   & 7  & \(Formula_7=M-N \)\\ 
        &   & 7a \\
        & N & 7b \\
        &   & 8  & \(Formula_8=\dfrac{O}{P}\)\\ 
\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}
\caption{Hi, I am the caption.}
\label{measures}%
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]