# Make \addlinespace globally to work with all tables

Tags: tables, spacing, multirow

I found that useful command `\addlinespace[3pt]` to create an extra white border around the rows. See example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{multirow,booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\rowcolors{1}{gray!15}{gray!15}
\begin{tabular}{rrrrr}
\rowcolor{gray!50}
Header & 1     & 2     & 3     & 4 \\ \addlinespace[3pt]
Row1  & a     & b     & c     & d \\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & a1    & b1    & c1    & d1 \\ \addlinespace[3pt]
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{-2}[0]{*}{Multirow1}} & a2    & b2    & c2    & d2 \\
Row2  & aa    & ab    & ac    & ad \\ 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I also found commands like:

```
\setlength\extrarowheight{7pt}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
```

here: [vertical align and color in table with multirow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63924/vertical-align-and-color-in-table-with-multirow?rq=1)

But these two commands seem to just expand the whole row rather than that white border thing. However, you call it ;)

As I have a lot of tables with loads of rows, my question is how to make the command `\addlinespace[3pt]` globally so that I do not have to add it at the end of each single row for all tables.

Comment: `\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}` increases the whitespace above _and_ below the row. `\setlength\extrarowheight{7pt}` only above!

Answer (score 5):

I'm not so sure you want this additional space between *all* rows, particularly those where a `\multirow` is involved.

However, stating `\global\everycr{\addlinespace[3pt]}` in the first cell will do; remember to restore `\everycr` to its empty usual value at the end.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{multirow,booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\rowcolors{1}{gray!15}{gray!15}
\begin{tabular}{rrrrr}
\rowcolor{gray!50}
\global\everycr{\addlinespace[3pt]}%
Header & 1     & 2     & 3     & 4 \\
Row1  & a     & b     & c     & d \\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & a1    & b1    & c1    & d1 \\\addlinespace[-3pt]
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{-2}[0]{*}{Multirow1}} & a2    & b2    & c2    & d2 \\
Row2  & aa    & ab    & ac    & ad \\
\end{tabular}
\global\everycr{}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Notice that I put a countermanding `\addlinespace` between the two rows sharing their label.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you really want is global `rowsep` setting. So you may try `tblr` environment from the new LaTeX3 package [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\SetTblrInner{rowsep=2pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tblr}{
  colspec = {r|[1pt,white]rrrr},
  cell{3}{1} = {r=2}{m}, % multirow
  rows = {gray9},
  hlines = {1pt,white},
}
  Header    & 1     & 2     & 3     & 4  \\
  Row1      & a     & b     & c     & d  \\
  Multirow1 & a1    & b1    & c1    & d1 \\
            & a2    & b2    & c2    & d2 \\
  Row2      & aa    & ab    & ac    & ad \\ 
\end{tblr}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]