# In latex, how to paint columns in a table?

Tags: tables

I can make the following table:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry} 

\usepackage{xcolor} 

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}

\begin{tabular}{|c||c|c||c|c||c|c||c|c||c|c||c|c|}

\hline

Caixa & $a_{i}$&$n_{i}$ & $a_{i}$&$n_{i}$ & $a_{i}$&$n_{i}$ & $a_{i}$&$n_{i}$ & $a_{i}$&$n_{i}$ & $a_{i}$&$n_{i}$ \\

\hline

10&10&1&10&1&10&1&10&1&10&0&0&1\\

\hline

9&8&1&8&1&8&1&8&1&8&1&9&1\\

\hline

8&6&1&6&1&6&1&6&1&6&1&7&1\\

\hline

7&4&1&4&1&4&1&4&1&4&1&5&1\\

\hline

6&2&1&2&1&2&1&2&1&2&1&3&1\\

\hline

5&0&1&5&2&5&2&5&2&5&2&1&1\\

\hline

4&2&2&1&2&1&2&1&2&1&2&3&2\\

\hline

3&1&3&0&3&0&3&3&3&3&4&2&3\\

\hline

2&1&6&0&6&2&7&1&7&1&7&2&0\\

\hline

1&1&17&1&19&1&2&1&2&1&21&1&17\\

\hline

\textbf{TOTAL}&35&&37&&39&&39&&41&&33&\\

\hline

\end{tabular}

\end{center}

\end{document}
```

But I would like to paint the columns as shown in the figure.

[image]

Comment: You can highlight code in your post using back-ticks. To highlight code-blocks, either indent them by four spaces or use the `{}` on the gui.

Comment: You can use [xcolor](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xcolor) to color the cells of a table. See [How to make a visually good table](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238503/tip-on-how-to-make-a-visually-good-table/238511#238511) for an example.

Comment: before you will going to coloring table, see https://wiert.me/2014/04/03/andre-vatter-google-wie-tabellen-eigentlich-aussehen-sollten-%EF%BB%BF/

Comment: Andrew - In the example suggested, are colored lines. I think I know how to do. But, paint only the columns I can't yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Her is a solution: it uses the `colortbl` package, loaded by xcolor`with option`[table]`. I also used`hhline`for nicer-looking horizontal lines (in my opinion) and I added some vertical padding to the rows with`extrarowheight`:
    \documentclass{article}

```
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage[table, x11names]{xcolor}

\usepackage{array, hhline, amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}
\begin{tabular}{|c|*{6}{|>{\columncolor{OliveDrab3!60}}c|>{\columncolor{Yellow1!80}}c|}}

\hhline{|-|*{6}{|--|}}

Caixa & $a_{i}$&$n_{i}$ & $a_{i}$&$n_{i}$ & $a_{i}$&$n_{i}$ & $a_{i}$&$n_{i}$ & $a_{i}$&$n_{i}$ & $a_{i}$&$n_{i}$ \\

\hhline{|-|*{6}{|--|}}

10&10&1&10&1&10&1&10&1&10&0&0&1\\

\hhline{|-|*{6}{|--|}}

9&8&1&8&1&8&1&8&1&8&1&9&1\\

\hhline{|-|*{6}{|--|}}

8&6&1&6&1&6&1&6&1&6&1&7&1\\

\hhline{|-|*{6}{|--|}}

7&4&1&4&1&4&1&4&1&4&1&5&1\\

\hhline{|-|*{6}{|--|}}

6&2&1&2&1&2&1&2&1&2&1&3&1\\

\hhline{|-|*{6}{|--|}}

5&0&1&5&2&5&2&5&2&5&2&1&1\\

\hline

4&2&2&1&2&1&2&1&2&1&2&3&2\\

\hhline{|-|*{6}{|--|}}

3&1&3&0&3&0&3&3&3&3&4&2&3\\

\hhline{|-|*{6}{|--|}}

2&1&6&0&6&2&7&1&7&1&7&2&0\\

\hhline{|-|*{6}{|--|}}

1&1&17&1&19&1&2&1&2&1&21&1&17\\

\hhline{|-|*{6}{|--|}}

\textbf{TOTAL}&35&&37&&39&&39&&41&&33&\\

\hhline{|-|*{6}{|--|}}

\end{tabular}

\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Bernard - Perfect! Show!